# SVG as a CSS background

Tags: html, css, svg

I've been trying to get a simple SVG rectangle to work as a background in IE9 or FF4 and neither is working for me. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:99px;background-image: url('bar.svg')"></div>
<iframe src="bar.svg" height="99px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

The iframe shows the graphic but the div does not. Any ideas where I may be going wrong?

I found a working example [here](http://www.helephant.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/svg1.html):
But I can't make it work myself :(
It's been driving me crazy.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you post code or a demo of this page in action? The code looks fine to me (but I'd add quotes `url('foo')` and change `background` to `background-image`).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to a web server. But I've used the above css for png images and it works fine.

Comment: Agree with blender.  I suspect the missing quotes around the URL are what is biting you.

Comment: I've modified the style as suggested but the result is the same.

Comment: @Rozwel, @Blender: Quotes are not required for the `url` accessor. This site gives an example of using an SVG image as a CSS background: http://www.alistapart.com/d/using-svg-for-flexible-scalable-and-fun-backgrounds-part-ii/example2.html

Comment: Can you post a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) so we can have a look? The code looks fine to me too.

Comment: That's a good simple example. From what I've seen so far. It works on body but not on a div ?!? Never used jsfiddle.net..I'll try.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help. It actually was a web server problem where the wrong MIME type for SVG was being served & that made the browsers fail to render correctly.

Here's what fixed it for me.

1st I switched from VS 2010's built-in web server to IIS Express. Then in my web config I added:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Now everything works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem in Joomla! 2.5 running on Godaddy Linux server.

After intense research here is how I fixed the problem:

Go to the root directory of your Joomla install and locate the *.htaccess* file (or *htaccess.txt* if it is not already setup)

Now add these lines to the file:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg
AddType image/svg+xml svgz
```

Rest, use the standard CSS and HTML properties to render your SVG file.

Answer (score 1):

Does this jsfiddle work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/B3mnk/embedded/result/

fwiw, I've added a background size to make it nice 'n big.

Comment: Yes it does. I starting to think the problem is actually not with the code but w/ Visual Studio 2010. I can run the pages locally or on-line, but if I try to run them in VS only the iframe works... very strange.

Comment: I'm afraid I know nothing of Visual Studio 2010. If you run them in VS, what browser is being used? Is it something built-in?

Answer (score 0):

Some articles with examples:

https://jwatt.org/svg/demos/xhtml-with-inline-svg.xhtml

http://helephant.com/2009/08/svg-images-as-css-backgrounds/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/svg_in_html_introduction

http://www.broken-links.com/2010/06/08/using-svg-in-background-image/ - This one has a fallback to .png near the bottom of the article.

Reported as a bug in Firefox:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=231179